# La différence entre « une chambre de bois » et « une chambre du bois »

Tags: sens, prépositions, articles

Je crois que « une chambre de bois » désigne une chambre qui contient du bois et que « une chambre du bois » désigne une chambre qui est faite du bois. Est-ce que j'ai raison ? Si c'est ça, est-ce qu'il y a un terme de grammaire pour cette distinction que je pourrais rechercher afin d'en apprendre plus ?

Comment: Au Québec, on dit généralement shed à bois (même si l'expression est incorrecte). Je n'ai jamais entendu "chambre de bois" ou "chambre du bois"

Comment: En France on dirait « un local à bois » pour le lieu où le bois est stocké.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Introduction:

Quelques réflexions:

On peut dire « une chambre en bois » ou « une chambre de bois » pour parler d'une pièce dont les murs apparents sont en bois. Je préfère la première forme (*en*), ne serait-ce que pour ne pas risquer d'être confondu avec *une jambe de bois*.

Je dirais « une chambre à bois » ou « une chambre pour le bois » avant de dire « une chambre du bois ». Cependant, dans un contexte familier on peut distinguer:

> … la chambre des enfants à gauche et la chambre du bois au fond…

Nota: à l'oreille, je peux concevoir *la chambre du bois* plus facilement que *la chambre des vélos*; Dans les deux cas *à* est préférable.

> La chambre des enfants, le local à vélo et le local à bois.

Utiliser *chambre* pour un « local d'entreposage » ne me semble pas indiqué.

#### A propos de chambre

Une chambre d'enfant est une chambre prévue pour loger un ou des enfants.

A contrario, ***la*** chambre **de l'**enfant est *unique*, mentionnée (notion de propriété ou d'attribution exclusif). N'est donc pas la chambre d'un autre enfant (sauf accord préalable de *l'enfant*).

Cette forme sonne un brin *excessif* ou *lourd*. En effet: *la chambre d'enfant* suffit à mentionner un local s'il est le seul et s'il y a plusieurs chambres d'enfants, alors nommer l'enfant devient nécessaire:

> La chambre de Jules

Curieusement *à* revient, ici, mais n'a plus tout à fait le même sens:

> La chambre à Jules

Ici le *à* a un sens de *propriété*, alors que pour le « le local à charbon » le *à* a un sens d'*assignation*.

#### Conclusion (Selon moi et mon oreille :)

On dit *une chambre en bois* pour parler d'un local destiné au logement et qui est tapissé de bois.

On dit *un local à bois* pour parler d'un entrepôt.

On dit *une chambre d'enfant en bois* pour parler d'un local boisé destiné à loger un ou des enfants.

On dit *la chambre d'enfant*, voire *la chambre des enfants* lorsque l'on sait de quelle chambre on parle.

Familièrement, on pourrait dire: *la chambre du gosse*, *la chambre du fils*, *la chambre de la fille*, *la chambre à Caroline*.

#### Addendum

Ces propos me sont personnels, je suppose qu'ils risquent de *plus ou moins* correspondre en fonction de la région linguistique. Je pense effectivement que ce genre d'habitudes du *parlé commun* varie fortement entre Marseille, Bergues, Bruxelles, Lausanne ou Montréal.

Comment: Merci pour votre explication. Je me suis cependant rendu compte que je n'étais pas précis dans ma question (voyez ma réponse à mouviciel pour plus de détails).

Comment: Mais pour *la chambre à air*, il ne s'agit pas de propriété...

Comment: @bronxbomber92: I've added some ideas about *la chambre de l'enfant*

Comment: Merci beaucoup, votre explication m'aide beaucoup !

Comment: @F.Hauri Sans oublier l'Afrique, le plus grand nombre de francophones, les îles (*département*, *territoire français*, *pays* outre-mer: DOM-TOM et POM).

Comment: @cl-r Bien sûr, d'autant que le français enseigné de force lors des colonisations me semble nécessairement plus teinté de coloration locales (résistance).

Comment: Étrange choix que Bergues car on y parle encore le flamand.

Comment: @Knu Je reconnais: c'était *facile*. Je cherchais deux extrêmes nord-sud... Cela dit, je ne suis pas une référence en géographie non plus :-p

Answer (score 7):

Pour moi, une *chambre de bois* est une chambre faite en bois ou dont les murs sont recouverts de bois.

Une *chambre du bois* me semble plus étrange. Je le comprends comme un groupe dont l'intérêt commun est le bois, une expression qui emprunterait à la fois à *chambre de commerce* et à *institut du pétrole*.

Pour signifier une *chambre qui contient du bois* avec une seule préposition, je dirais plutôt une *chambre à bois*, bien que cette expression aussi me semble étrange. Sans doute parce que généralement la fonction principale d'une chambre n'est pas d'y stocker des biens (à part *chambre froide*).

Quant à une *chambre qui fait du bois*, je n'ai pas d'inspiration. En général on dit *scierie* pour un endroit où on transforme les troncs en planches et *menuiserie* pour un endroit où on transforme les planches en meubles.

Comment: (+) Excellente réponse à une question assez étrange... étant donné que les deux expressions à distinguer sont toutes les deux inattendues ou disons inusitées.

Comment: Pour désigner une “chambre” qui contient du bois, j’utilise “bûcher”, personnellement.

Comment: Je suis désolé pour l'exemple étrange. J'ai principalement intéressé par le distinction du grammaire, et j'avais difficulté en développant un exemple puisque je ne connais pas bien le grammaire ! La construction qui me confond est la suivant: « noun + "de" + l'article défini + noun » vs « noun + "de" + noun ». Peut-être que je devrais ouvre une autre "thread" parce que je n'étais pas précis ici?

Comment: @bronxbomber92 Un exemple plus commun derait peut-être « chambre d'enfant » et « chambre de l'enfant »?

Comment: Oui, je pense que celles marcheraient ! « chambre d'enfant » signifierait donc une chambre plein d'enfants, et  « chambre de l'enfant » signifierait une chambre qui appartient à un enfant ?

Comment: Joli! J'ai dû le relire 2 fois pour comprendre `Chambre du Bois` comme `département du bois` dans, p. ex. des institutions publiques! Effectivement, dans ce sens là, cette forme peut être *adéquate* mais à la limite du *nom propre*, je l'écrirais *capitalisée*.

Answer (score 4):

"Bois" présente une difficulté particulière : il peut s'agir de la matière lignée, d'un produit ou d'un matériau qu'on peut stocker (comme les pommes, le charbon, la terre, l'eau), mais aussi d'une petite forêt.

Prenons un autre exemple :

- une caisse à pommes : une caisse destinée à y stocker des pommes
- une caisse de pommes : une caisse pleine de pommes (la caisse est pris dans son sens de "volume", comme on dirait "un kilo de pommes")
- une caisse de bois : une caisse pleine de bois OU une caisse faite avec du bois (cela dépend du contexte)
- une caisse en bois : une caisse faite avec du bois
- une caisse à bois : une caisse destinée à y ranger du bois
- on pourrait dire "la caisse de Marie" : la caisse qui appartient à Marie, celle de Marie
- mais pas "une caisse de Marie", sauf contexte spécial : une caisse (qui me vient) de Marie, ou "une (des) caisses de Marie"
- quant à "une caisse à Marie" ou "la caisse à Marie" : ne s'utilisent pas du tout en français correct (sauf si l'on dit "j'ai donné la caisse à Marie" - c'est à Marie que j'ai donné cette caisse, "caisse" et "à Marie" peuvent être séparés sans changer le sens de la phrase)

Donc, on peut voir que le sens de "de", "en" et "à" diffère selon que l'on parle de **personnes, d'objets, ou de matière**.

Pour en revenir à la chambre (pièce qui d'ordinaire sert de lieu de repos et de sommeil - bedroom - ou qui a un usage particulier - chambre froide, Chambre de Commerce, etc.) voici mon avis sur les différents usages (en France) :

- une chambre d'enfant : une chambre prévue pour un ou des enfants, destinée à être habitée par un enfant.

*"Il nous faudra une chambre d'enfant : je suis enceinte !"*

- la chambre d'enfant(s) : la pièce de la maison qui a été prévue pour un ou des enfants. Il n'y en a qu'une, et c'est de cette pièce qu'on est en train de parler.

*"Et voici la chambre d'enfant : comme vous le voyez, elle est grande et lumineuse ! Vous pourrez joliment l'aménager !"*

- la chambre des enfants : la chambre dans laquelle dorment nos enfants, les enfants de la maison en question.

*"Et voici la chambre des enfants : Marie dort au fond à gauche, et Arthur ici, à côté de la porte."*

- Idem pour "la chambre de l'enfant, de Marie" : il s'agit d'une chambre dans laquelle un enfant particulier, le seul de la maison s'il n'est pas précisé, ou Marie dans cet exemple, est installé.
- la chambre à enfant, à Marie : ne s'utilise pas.
- cas particulier : "une chambre d'enfants" peut exceptionnellement signifier "une chambre remplie d'enfants"... on dirait plutôt "une chambre pleine d'enfants braillards" (remplie d'enfants qui braillent, qui crient, pleurent, etc.) ou "une pleine chambre d'enfants braillards" (assez d'enfants bruyants pour en remplir une chambre, qu'ils soient réellement dans une chambre, ou non. S'utilise pour appuyer l'idée qu'il y a beaucoup, beaucoup d'enfants, et surtout qui font beaucoup, beaucoup de bruit).
- la chambre à bois : destinée à y ranger du bois - peu usité, on préférera un autre mot que "chambre".
- une chambre de, en bois : faite de bois, comme une cabane de bois, une maison en bois.

Mais si l'on dit "J'ai rempli une pleine chambre de bois", cela ne signifie pas qu'elle est en bois, mais qu'on l'a remplie avec du bois. "Chambre" est pris dans le sens d'un volume, et non d'un lieu particulier. On peut d'ailleurs séparer "de bois" de "pleine chambre" : "J'ai rempli de bois une pleine chambre". Mais comme il a été dit "chambre" ne s'utilise pas, en général, dans ce sens.

Par contre, "la maison du/des bois" n'a rien à voir : "bois" ici a le sens de "forêt", il s'agit d'une maison qui se trouve dans le bois (et c'est la seule, c'est "LA" maison du/des bois, tout le monde sait de quoi on parle).

J'espère que ceci complète utilement, quoiqu'un peu tardivement, les autres exemples et propositions (j'imagine que ce post date de 2013, rien ne semble le préciser, je ne vois que le jour et le mois).