# Comment et pourquoi « revenir » peut-il signifier « s'y ramener » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Je me suis aperçu d'un usage inhabituel de *revenir* dans [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7456/la-difference-entre-une-chambre-de-bois-et-une-chambre-du-bois/7459#7459), d'où provient ceci :

> > La chambre de Jules
>
> Curieusement *à* **revient**, ici, mais n'a plus tout à fait le même sens:
>
> > La chambre à Jules
>
> Ici le *à* a un sens de *propriété*, alors que pour le « le local à charbon » le *à* a un sens d'*assignation*.

Je n'avais jamais imaginé que *s'y ramener* en serait un synonyme. En conséquence, j'ai recouru au [Larousse](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/revenir/69087?q=revenir#68332) qui indique :

> Être équivalent à quelque chose d'autre, s'y ramener. Exemple : Cela revient en fait à une rupture.

1. Comment déduire que *revenir* signifie « s'y ramener » ?
2. Comment peut-on trouver plus d'exemples de *revenir* dans ce contexte, à part sur CNTRL qui ne fournit qu'une poignée d'exemples ? Entrer *revenir* dans Google Livres n'amène qu'à d'autres contextes hors du propos, et pas à celui recherché.

Comment: La *chambre à Jules* n'est pas correcte, même si cette tournure est employée familièrement par les enfants. La propriété de Jules, la maison de Jules (il peut tout aussi bien être locataire), la chambre de Jules, celle qui lui est réservée.

Comment: *Revient* n'est pas dans cette phrase un synonyme de "se ramener à". *Revient* a le sens "réapparaître" ([sens I.B. du TLFQ](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/revenir)), "se ramener à" signifie "se réduire à, être simplifiable pour devenir" ([sens III.2-3](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ramener)). Ce sens existe aussi pour *revenir* (sens II.3.a, d'ailleurs défini "se ramener à"), mais n'a pas ce sens dans ton premier exemple.

Comment: Son sens *culinaire* est probablement le plus "inhabituel".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans le passage que tu cites, *revenir* signifie « venir à nouveau », « surgir à nouveau ». F. Hauri aurait pu écrire « Curieusement, le mot *à* est à nouveau possible, ici, mais n'a plus tout à fait le même sens: (...) ».

*Revenir* signifie en général « venir à nouveau », mais peut s'employer plus largement dans des sens abstraits. Par exemple, « revenir sur le tapis » (légèrement familier) signifie que quelque chose redevient un sujet de conversation, alors qu'on ne dirait pas « *<s>venir sur le tapis</s> ».

> Lors de la réunion de lundi, nous avons discuté d'une nouvelle proposition visant à agrandir les locaux.
>   Lors de la réunion de jeudi, la proposition visant à agrandir les locaux est revenue sur le tapis.

*Revenir* peut bien sûr être suivi d'un complément de lieu.

> Je reviens à Paris ce soir. = Je rentre à Paris ce soir.

*Revenir à* est aussi un idiome qui a un sens différent. C'est le sens II.D.3.a du [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/revenir). Le sens est à peu près le même que *se ramener à*. « A revient à B » ou « A se ramène à B » signifie que si l'on peut faire B, l'on peut aussi faire A ; ou que faire A implique de faire B. Dans les deux cas, l'intuition est que B est la manière naturelle de procéder, et que si l'on essaie de faire A à la place, A pousse à revenir vers B (A ramène vers B).

« A se ramène à B » implique que pour faire A, il faut faire B plus autre chose ; B est la partie principale de A. J'ai rarement vu cette expression hors du contexte d'une démonstration logique ou d'un raisonnement scientifique. « A revient à B » implique que faire A ou faire B est à peu près équivalent, ou au moins que l'on peut passer directement de A à B.

> En somme, toute son éloquence revenait à ceci : « Entre Santos Iturria et moi, vous avez choisi (…) » (Larbaud)

« Toute son éloquence était équivalente à ceci : « (…) » ». (Autrement dit, la personne dont il est question avait beaucoup parlé, mais le contenu de son discours tient en la phrase citée.)

> Augmenter les salaires reviendrait à fermer boutique.

« Si on augmentait les salaires, l'entreprise s'arrêterait de fonctionner » (l'étape sous-entendue étant que l'entreprise n'aurait pas les moyens de payer des salaires plus élevés).

> Le cas d'un polygone quelconque se ramène à celui d'un triangle.

« Si l'on sait résoudre le problème pour un triangle, on en déduit facilement une méthode pour un polygone quelconque. »

Answer (score 0):

*venir*, est ici symbolique, il marque le cheminement de la pensée, *revenir* signe un nouveau passage  ; une redite pour confirmer, valider la chose déjà dite ou un contexte synonyme (souvent utilisé dans "cela revient au même").
Seul un objet mobile, une personne peut *revenir*.

*amener* [mener (un être animé) auprès de quelqu'un] : accompagner ; *ramener*, c'est l'accompagner une deuxième (ou énième) fois.
Toujours dans le domaine symbolique, on *ramène* la pensée de l'autre, et donc on *y ramène* la conversation.

> - ... pour conclure cet exemple booléen, cela *revient à* dire que 1 + 1 = 1

Signification de quelque chose d'identique, en général dans le contexte de ce qui est dit.

> - ... et donc la conclusion de cette exposé, *se ramène* à celle de l'exposé précédent

Reconduite de l'attention sur une point de vue déjà évoqué hors du strict contexte évoqué.

- La pensée vient et *revient* d'elle-même.
- La pensée amène et *ramène* l'attention selon les nécessités du discours.
  *Explicitation demandée* :

    « "*La pensée amène et ramène*", est la manifestation de l'attention de l'attention, soit un moyen de parvenir au deuxième niveau de la conscience : 
  La conscience attentive aux perceptions sensorielles est le niveau naturel du vécu, on a l'impression que la pensée *amène* quelques manifestations de la réalité dans le langage, on vit dans le monde de la dualité où des 'objets' sont perçus.
  L'esprit silencieux (contrairement à son habitude de vouloir faire et agir par la parole) est attentif à ce que la conscience est en train de percevoir, on a alors la sensation que l'esprit et la conscience sont indissociables, que la pensée *ramène* au centre d'intérêt tout ce qui se trouve alentours, s’ouvre alors une porte sur le monde de la non-dualité, où la conscience reflète une réalité authentique. »

"Cela nous ramène à dire ..." , est différent de "cela revient à dire ...", dans le premier cas, on fait un retour en arrière dans le fil de ce qui vient d'être dit, dans le second, c'est la conclusion qui est confirmée.

Comment: Je vous suis reconnaissant. Plussoyé. Dans le dernier paragraphe de votre réponse, `...ramène l'attention...`, est-ce une confirmation de la conclusion ? Prière de riposter dans votre réponse SVP.

Comment: @LePressentiment Quitte à paraître laborieux, j'ai essayé de préciser les mécanismes qui sous-tendent la pensée engagée dans un discours sincère où l'on cher l'expression d'une vérité.